# Promise.all not working for all items, unless I change the order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Ok, this is seriously making me lose my mind...

```js
Promise.all([
    one(code),
    two(code),
    three(code),
    four(code),
    five(code),
    six(code),
    seven(code) // <----- This one
]).then(data => {
    // ...
}
```

The functions are nothing special...

```js
function seven() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fetch(`/api-route`) 
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data) {
                    resolve(data);
                } else {
                    reject({
                        status: "Retrieval failed."
                    });
                }
            });
    });
}
```

If I change the places of `six()` and `seven()`, then `seven()` works and `six()` no longer does... It makes no sense...

**Calling the API routes manually works**, but in the promise.all, they can't work after another? What am I missing?

Comment: Use async-await for in order execution

Comment: When some promise within your array failes, the returned promise from `Promise.all` will fail as well. This could cause this "issue".

Comment: I realized that the problem was not in the `promise.all` but rather the database connection i.e. `Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.`, preventing it to make the second call. My bad...

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!